# Email sending only once instead of multiple times

Tags: magento-1.9

once **Registered user** upload custom image on [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) and click on  Custom button "**save design**"

for each click on "save design" , we are creating new row in table : **"my_Designs"** & we are sending email when each row created.

[image]

suppose customer clicked on "save design" button 3 times after uploading 3 images at each time, only one [first] email is delivering to customer with first image.

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName() ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>" alt="Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName()" />
```

**Edit** : full code :

```
hi <?php echo $this->getCustomerName() ?>,
<br>


<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName() ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>" alt="Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName()" />

<br>

<center>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->getRestoreCartUrl() ?>" class="button">Finish Checkout</a>
</center>
```

Comment: Could you add a code by which you are sending emails?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau please check `edit` part in question, i am using only those code to send emails.....

Comment: Update your Controller email code. this is not email code

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for support.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are using 3rd party module to send emails, there was a configuration in that for sending email on time basis. Once we removed that settings, now we can able to send email per each second....